# Macbook pro keyboard stuck issue

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I have 15 inch macbook pro , i am facing issue with keys , `option key` is automatically pressed and becoming active all the time when i press any key in marked red zone in image . the Left Option is not working and `Right Option key` is working , when i press twice `option key` , than it is inactive (i tested after enabling hot key from preferences ) .

Here is the keyboard image
[image]

for ex. if i press `Space key` or `right shift` or `enter` then `Option key` is becoming active .

What is the possible fix for this ??

Comment: Hardware issues are best handled by a service technician.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues. Found a fix around. This app (Unshaky) will stop your mac from pressing keys multiple times (you have to configure the app, its pretty simple and straight forward). my problem was that my keyboard kept on pressing the `option key` instead of just holding. This app worked with me.. Hope it helps.

link found [here](https://github.com/Aahung/Unshaky)

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Unshaky has literally saved my sanity.  Can't thank you enough for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Apple are currently offering [free keyboard repairs](https://www.apple.com/support/keyboard-service-program-for-macbook-and-macbook-pro/) on many 2015 through 2017 MacBook and MacBook Pro models, even if they’re out of warranty. If you have one of those models then back it up and book a Genius Bar appointment.